# How to identify type of authorization?

Tags: request, soapui

I need to identify type of authorization on web-site to set-up this authorization in soapui request.

When I log in there is 'auth' POST-method detected in google chrome Network tab: https://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/auth? with payload {"login":"some_login","password":"some_passw"}

And when I do this request in SoapUI as POST HTTP request: https://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/auth?login=some_login&password=some_passw ; there is a responce of json format which contains "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIiwgImFs..."

I want to set up athorization for another method on this web-site, so first of all I need to know the type of authorization to set up in soapui Auth Tab:

[image: Auth Tab]

[image: Auth types]

**UPDATE:**

Token is not used in HTTP request types, it is available in e.g. REST request:

[image]

But I still can not make this token work

Comment: Not much help here but try to dig around some of the SO links that come up, maybe it will help [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US725&ei=U331W62aKdGXtgXQ2YHwDA&q=json+auth+token+stackoverflow&oq=json+auth+token+stackoverflow&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30.23745.26584..26760...0.0..0.120.1188.13j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30j33i160j33i299.JQqXiKbbh0Q)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was looking for the wrong type of athorization. All above is about server uthorization. But I need to complete web-app authorization.

So just using token in Header params of SoapUI did the trick:

[image]